# reverse the name string from extracting mail

Tags: r

I am looking for a script to extract name from email. and then reverse the name string for example
email = ram.singh.tak@zzzz.com  then extract **ram.singh.tak** from email and replace "." with space like
**ram singh tak** and then mutate data frame with new column with reverse name like **tak singh ram**

```
df <-  data.frame(name= c("ali wing sam","nick jone","mak liam","r mush","sink dude"),
                  Email = c("sam.wing.ali@xyz.com","nick.jone@xyz.com","liam.mak@xyz.com","r.mush@xyz.com","dude.sink@xyz.com"))

separator = " "


df %>%
  
  mutate(across(all_of(c(name, Email)), tolower)) %>% 
  
  mutate(email_name = str_extract(!!sym(Email), "([a-z.]+)(?=@.+)")) %>% 
  
  mutate(email_name = str_replace_all(email_name, "\\.", separator))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(email_name = str_extract(Email, '.*(?=@)')) %>% 
  separate(col = email_name, into = c('f','s','l'), sep = '\\.') %>% 
  mutate(l = replace_na(l, ''), email_name_rev = str_c(l,s,f, sep = ' ')) %>% 
  select(name, Email, email_name_rev)
          name                Email email_name_rev
1 ali wing sam sam.wing.ali@xyz.com   ali wing sam
2    nick jone    nick.jone@xyz.com      jone nick
3     mak liam     liam.mak@xyz.com       mak liam
4       r mush       r.mush@xyz.com         mush r
5    sink dude    dude.sink@xyz.com      sink dude
```

Comment: How to handle if NA and blank cells in email column

Comment: @newcomer, any NA or blanks will result in NA in the newly created column.

Comment: I am trying to match name and name in email after extracting name from email and reverse of name in email . sometimes  separator can be comma "," or "." or " "space in name column. thats why i am giving input parameter as separator for user

Comment: trying this approach     df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(name,Email), tolower)) %>% 
  mutate(email_name1 = str_extract(Email, '.*(?=@)')) %>% 
  mutate(email_name1 = str_replace_all(email_name1, "\\.", separator)) %>% 
  
  mutate(email_name = str_extract(Email, '.*(?=@)')) %>% 
  separate(col = email_name, into = c('f','s','l'), sep = '\\.') %>%
  mutate(l = replace_na(l,''), email_name_rev = str_c(l,s,f, sep = separator)) %>% 
select(-c("f","s","l")) 
df$email_name_rev <- str_squish(df$email_name_rev)
df <- df %>%  mutate(match1 = +(name == email_name_rev | name == email_name1))

Comment: but output is coming strange . do you have any solution...???

Answer (score 0):

This `base R` solution uses nested `sub` operations and multiple backreference to recollect and reorder the name components:

```
df$name_rev <- sub("^(\\.|\\s)", "", 
                   sub("([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+)(\\.([a-z]+))?.*", "\\3 \\2 \\1", df$Email, perl = T))
          name                Email     name_rev
1 ali wing sam sam.wing.ali@xyz.com ali wing sam
2    nick jone    nick.jone@xyz.com    jone nick
3     mak liam     liam.mak@xyz.com     mak liam
4       r mush       r.mush@xyz.com       mush r
5    sink dude    dude.sink@xyz.com    sink dude
```

Comment: How to handle if NA and blank cells in email column

Comment: You mean like this? `df <-  data.frame(name= c("ali wing sam", "nick jone","mak liam","r mush","sink dude"),
                  Email = c("sam.wing.ali@xyz.com","NA","liam.mak@xyz.com","r.mush@xyz.com",""))`. The code given in my answer handles these cases too.

Comment: On my end, the solution I provided in my answer accounts for `""` and `NA`. If it does on your end too please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`'s `str_extract` and `str_split` we can extract the name for email then apply rev to the elements and paste them together:

```r
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
 mutate(splits=map(str_split(str_extract(Email, ".+?(?=@)"), "\\."), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) . else paste0(rev(.), collapse=" ")))
          name                Email       splits
1 ali wing sam sam.wing.ali@xyz.com ali wing sam
2    nick jone    nick.jone@xyz.com    jone nick
3     mak liam     liam.mak@xyz.com     mak liam
4       r mush       r.mush@xyz.com       mush r
5    sink dude    dude.sink@xyz.com    sink dude
```

Comment: How to handle if NA and blank cells in email column

Comment: @newcomer It'll just give you `"NA"`. The new answer will leave the value as `NA`